# What does an 'S' in a hex number mean?

Tags: vb.net, hex

Trying to convert some vb.net code to c#, I ran into this:

```
Dim b As Byte = &HCS
```

The actual value of this is `&H0C`, or 12 decimal. What does the inclusion of the 'S' character do in this context?

Comment: The hex literal is a ***S**hort* (int16 instead of the default int32) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Whoops, wrote my answer too slowly. You can post yours instead, @AlexK.

Comment: Vincent's got it covered, you can accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a so-called *Type Character*. It's used as a short-hand for declaring constant values of a specific type. In your case `S` turns the value of `&HC` into a `Short` (Int16).

They're normally used like this, when you don't specify the type of the variable in the form of `As [type]`:

```
Dim number = 56L 'This makes 'number' a variable of type Long.
```

As there is no character for declaring a `Byte`, I guess the original creator of that line used the closest possible - a `Short`.

**Read more:** [**Type Characters (Visual Basic) | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters)